# Find and soft link without the parent path

Tags: find, pipe, exec, ln

So I have a find command as below which finds the `libclntsh.so.*` files in a directory `instantclient`.

```
find instantclient -type f -name "*libclntsh\.so\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

This results in for e.g.,

```
instantclient/libclntsh.so.11.1
```

How do I now `ln` within `instantclient` directory, `ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so` all with a `find` command in combination with `exec`

I should mention here that I DO NOT want to `cd` into `instantclient`.
And this is for Alpine Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-execdir` option. As per manual:

> `-execdir command {} ;`
>
> Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched  file,  which  is  not normally  the  directory in which you started find.  This a much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files.

So your command will be:

```
 find instantclient -type f -name "*libclntsh\.so\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" -execdir ln -s {} libclntsh.so \;
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution

```
 find instantclient -type f -name "*libclntsh\.so\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" | xargs -I {} sh -c 'ln -s $(basename {}) instantclient/libclntsh.so'
```

Comment: Neither did I :) I was just checking how exactly `-exec` works and found it in the man page.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this ? `-execdir` doesnt exist as an option in Alpine Linux's find which is probably why i didnt see.